# Firebase Reference in background service is not setPersistenceEnabled

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

spent like 3 hours searching the solution, but couldn't.

I use Firebase database and whenever I use it from activity/fragment everything works fine, but whenever I try to use it from background service it crashed the app, even though I initiate it (and setPersistent enable at first) before using.

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: dreamchasers.com.coinpal, PID: 8565
                                                                    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.zziF(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at dreamchasers.com.coinpal.services.FirebaseBackgroundService.getDatabase32(FirebaseBackgroundService.java:297)
                                                                        at dreamchasers.com.coinpal.services.FirebaseBackgroundService.queryAlerts(FirebaseBackgroundService.java:85)
                                                                        at dreamchasers.com.coinpal.services.FirebaseBackgroundService.onStartJob(FirebaseBackgroundService.java:70)
                                                                        at com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService.start(JobService.java:127)
                                                                        at com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(JobServiceConnection.java:65)
                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1516)
                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1544)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

My background service firebase reference init method:

```
    public static DatabaseReference getDatabase32() {
    if (mDatabase == null) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    }
    return mDatabase;
}
```

Please help, any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
Everytime I'm using setPersistenceEnabled, I'm doing it via app.java

Just create class like that:

```
public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

All you need for this to work, is put in `application` tag in AndroidManifest.xml attribute android:name=".App".

```
<!-- other xml stuff -->

<application ... android:name=".App">

   <!-- yet another stuff like nextline -->
   <activity ... />
</application>
```

Comment: Is this will be initiated when app is closed and only background services is running ?